Implicit function declaration
I just ran basic hello world code in VS code(c language)
Then I went to terminal and wrote "gcc '.\first project.c'"  (first project.c is the file name).
I got this
PS C:\Users\user\Documents\VS CODES> gcc '.\first project.c'
.\first project.c: In function 'main':
.\first project.c:4:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'print' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     print("Hello World");
     ^~~~~
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGIZDx0.o:first project.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `print
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

There was question similar to this but the answers were hoshposh. I wasn't able to get anything.
I know this question might be dumb but I am just a beginner so.
ran the hello world code
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    print("Hello World");
    return 0;   
}

I then went to the compiler and tried to run with gcc but the aforementioned code came in the terminal...
I've searched it on stack overflow and got the question but the answers are all messy.
Please explain to me in layman's terms.

Which hello world example tells you to use the function print()?

"implicit declaration of function" essentially means that you are attempting to use a function without having previously defined or declared it. You got this because instead of printf, you typed print and you don't have a function "print". Implicit function declarations were more of a thing 35 or more years ago and were disallowed as of C99. Translate this message to "Error: attempt to use function without prior prototype declaration or definition." and then fix the code.

The stdio.h command for printing to the console is printf, not print.
Try switching line 4 to the following:
printf("Hello World");

Here's some documentation for the printf() function:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cpp-printf-function/

It looks like you are using print("Hello World"); instead of printf("Hello World");
